# Is it possible to make double tables more efficiently coded?

Tags: performance-tuning, list-manipulation

I am wondering about the following situation, suppose I have

```
Table[Table[x^Length[l[[j]][[i]]], {i, Length[l[[1]]]}] // 
   Total, {j, Length[l]}];
```

where `l` is some list of the form:

```
l={{"a1","a2","a3","a4","a5","a6","a7","a8","a9","a10"},{"b1","b2","b3","b4","b5","b6","b7","b8","b9","b10"},{"c1","c2","c3","c4","c5","c6","c7","c8","c9","c10"},{"d1","d2","d3","d4","d5","d6","d7","d8","d9","d10"},{"e1","e2","e3","e4","e5","e6","e7","e8","e9","e10"}}
```

note that the list is just for illustration, in reality the length of my original list is 115000 and each element has length of 30. When I run above code it is taking a lot of time, I wonder if there is a better way when one deals with `Table[Table[]]` command?

Comment: I am not sure what `Length` is supposed to do here. Maybe you meant to use `StringLength`?

Comment: `Length` of a string returns `0` and `x^0` equals `1`; effectively what your code does is to count the number of entries in each sublist (that's what the `Total` part does) and output a list enumerating those counts; is this what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you may utilize that many arithmetic operations are `Listable`:

```
Total[x^Map[Length, l, {2}], {2}]
```

If `x` is numerical, it will probably be more efficient to perform a cast to a packed array:

```
Total[x^Developer`ToPackedArray[Map[Length, l, {2}]], {2}]
```